# Prevent variable value change when loop is in progress

Tags: java, asynchronous

I am trying to understand how can I prevent a particular variable from being changed by another thread while a loop is in progress. A typical code example is :

```
class() {
  private boolean maskValue = false; // has getter and setter
  public void myMethod () {
     list.parallelStream.forEach(item -> do_Stuff); // it is important to me that no one can change maskValue while parallelStream is not complete or until method execution is not complete. 
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought about synchronized on method name but thats not it.

Comment: Perhaps the issue here is that you're trying to protect something that wants to be mutable from an operation which doesn't want it to change. Perhaps pass the value into the parallelStream operation, so that the operation gets an immutable copy.

You can't stop things with getters and setters from being changed some of the time.. but passing copies of objects around generally helps things be "effectively immutable."

Comment: @AshleyFrieze You are right.